# Magento Transactional Emails Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, magento

We have amended transactional emails in Magento's admin panel and I can see these 'correct' versions in the mage_core_email_template table in the MySQL database.

However, the emails that turn up after a transaction are using the template files from `/public_html/app/locale/en_GB/template/email(/sales)` - note the en_GB folder in the middle.

These are an exact copy of the template files from the `en_US` folder. I'm not sure, but we may have foolishly done this after amending the admin panel templates - ho hum: I'm new to Magento.

Do the admin panel templates write to the the template file folders (`en_GB`)? And if so, if I delete the template files from the `en_GB` folder will they do it automatically or do I need to initiate it somehow (and how)?

If none of these, how do I get Magento to use the admin panel templates rather than the files in the locale folders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining an email template in the Admin is not sufficient, once created proper templates you have to associate them in the System, Configuration settings (changing Store View Scope) to override the default behavior that is applying templates from the file system. Maybe you were missing that final step.

Comment: Thank you so much Alessandro, that's exactly what it was. I was assuming it would be more complicated.